# Aks update workload to new image

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am running an azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

I have deployed an image to the azure container registry.

And the workload shows there.

But now I have to change some settings or update the code. I have published the new image to ACR.  But now I cannot find out how to tell AKS to start updating the pods to the latest image?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, AKS cannot update its application directly with the latest image when a new image version is available in ACR. I tried to achieve the same thing by setting image policies in manifest files, but it does not work for existing pods. Only the newly created pods will be able to pull the latest image.

But as per your requirement, you can utilize CICD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment) or GitOps methodologies for AKS. I suggest referring to the following links for detailed information:

1. [CI/CD for AKS apps with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/aks/aks-cicd-azure-pipelines)
2. [GitOps for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/gitops-aks/gitops-blueprint-aks)

These resources will provide you with guidance on configuring CICD pipelines or implementing GitOps practices in AKS to update your application with the latest available image from ACR.

Comment: OK so if I understand you, we must use dev ops to 1: push new image to ACR, then we it will programmatically tell the workload on aks to please create new instances and delete the old ones,  This will essentially force the workload to get the latest image.